# Files In templateParameters

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

In HtmlWebpackPlugin configurations when I specify templateParameters I no longer have access to my files in the template.

Webpack Config:

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ 
        template: './app/index.ejs', 
        inject: false, 
        templateParameters: configJSON 
    })
],
```

Template:

```
<script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js[0] %>"></script>
```

Is there a way to access files while using templateParameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked over the source code and found that `templateParameters` can also be a function and has the parameters `compilation`, `assets`, `options`. The assets parameter has all the files. The object returned from this function will be the `templateParameters`.

Comment: Just remember not to use `data` as the name of any of the keys in the top-level of the returned object

Comment: [Relevant source code](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/34d8aa572c7acc59c26f3b5d15bf489a07aa4c24/index.js#L369). And [the default function](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/34d8aa572c7acc59c26f3b5d15bf489a07aa4c24/index.js#L984).